# For loop check if string only has 3 capital letters followed by 4 numbers

Tags: c#, for-loop

I input a string that has to start with three capital letters and ending with four digits (like so: "SJL1036") the program is just supposed to check if my input follows that model.

if i were to input "Sjl1036" og "SJL103" it would output that it is a false statement.

Comment: Have you considered a regex to do so?

Comment: You didn't really ask a question here.  You just stated something.  Try rephrasing this to ask a specific question we can help you with.

Comment: How is the `for-loop` related at all?

Answer (score 6):

Try this regular expression. 3 uppercase, 4 numbers.

```
^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}$
```

For example:

```
var value = "FSK2526";
if (Regex.IsMatch(value, @"^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}$")) {
   // it matches
}
```

Comment: More information on how to achieve this with C# would help the OP.

Answer (score 4):

If this is the requirement:

> A string that has to start with three capital letters and ending with
>   four digits

Probably the most efficient approach is using [string method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_methods(v=vs.110).aspx)s:

```
bool valid = input.Length >= 7 
    && input.Remove(3).All(Char.IsUpper) // or input.Substring(0, 3)
    && input.Substring(input.Length - 4).All(Char.IsDigit);
```

If the actual requirement is "3 capital letters followed by 4 numbers"(so 7 characters) you just need to change `input.Length >= 7` to `input.Length == 7`.

Comment: Hmmm, this allows "ABC1234xxxxx"

Comment: Doesn't this fail for ABCd1011?

Comment: @DrKoch: No, it doesn't. `input.Substring(input.Length - 4).All(Char.IsDigit)` checks if the last four characters are digits.

Comment: @Michael: No, the requirement was:"Start with three capital letters and ending with four digits". `input.Remove(3).All(Char.IsUpper)` checks if the first three characters are uppercase and `input.Substring(input.Length - 4).All(Char.IsDigit)` if the last four characters are digits.

Comment: @TimSchmelter You're right. I made an assumption.

Comment: This question could be interpreted in multiple ways, but I think Tim got this one absolutely right.

Answer (score 4):

Although you could do it with for loop, but you could simplify it further with regex like:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[A-Z]{3}.*[0-9]{4}$");
Match match = regex.Match("SJL1036");
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A non-Regex option, You can use a bit of LINQ like:

```
string str = "SJL1036";
if (str.Length == 7 &&
    str.Take(3).All(char.IsUpper)
    && str.Skip(3).All(char.IsDigit))
{
    Console.WriteLine("valid");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("invalid");
}
```